# Do I need to make both variables volatile in reader/writer scenario?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrent-programming

We have 2 threads. One is a reader. The other is a writer thread who share these 2 variables:

```
Object data
boolean ready
```

Do I need to make both volatile? Is it sufficient to make 'ready' volatile?

```
write() {
    data = <some data>
    ready = true;
}

read() {
    if (ready) {
        consume(data);
        ready = false;
    } 
}
```

Do I need to make both variables volatile?

Based on my limited understnding of the java memory model, I think I only have to make 'ready' volatile as all the code before reading/writing 'ready' happens-before the code after the reading/writing of 'ready' variable?

Update: For the purposes of this question, assume that atomicity is not an issue. The production and consumption of data is atomic.

Comment: What about atomicity: while consuming data, it is updated again?

Answer (score 1):

volatiles are good for signaling as you are using but not for atomicity. You need atomicity in case data gets updated while it is being consumed but ready is not set yet.

Answer (score 1):

As has been made clear by others on the atomicity, you could increase the concurrency by using a ReadWriteLock. More details at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html

In this case there could be more than one reader threads and the write lock would be exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to another on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397445/atomicboolean-set-flag-once-neccesary-might-a-static-boolean-be-ok/28398083#28398083).

As I said there, if **data** and **ready** are only being updated by one thread then volatile works fine for **BOTH**. Atomic is for multiple writers.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.

When Thread 1 writes to a volatile variable and subsequently Thread 2 reads that volatile variable, all variables visible to Thread 1 before volatile write becomes visible to Thread 2 after volatile read. Just like Thread 1 leaves a synchronized block and subsequently Thread 2 enters.

But it is not a recommended way to provide visibility since it does not show itself explicitly like entering / exiting a synchronized block or acquiring / releasing a lock.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile variables are convenient for status flags like **ready** in your example but only guarantees accessing the value in a thread-safe manner, does not guarantee the rest of the blocks to be executed in order.

In your example, **write(data)** and **read()** operations may be executed in parallel and execution time of **consume(data)** may cause **read()** to be completed after 2nd call of **write(data)** which will procude **ready** variable to be setted as false even though it is expected to be true for the new data which is setted by the 2nd call of **write(data)**.

For example:

Thread 1 start: **write(data1)**

Thread 1 end: // ready: true, data = data1

Thread 2 starts: **read()** // consume(data1) takes a while.

Thread 3 starts: **write(data2)** // ready = true, data = data2

Thread 2 ends: **read()** // consume(data2) finished, ready = false, data = data2