# Android Concurrent : UI thread edit a variable and other thread read the same variable

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have one doubt relative concurrent between UI thread and other thread.

Ui main thread update the value of different variable :
- float
- long
- boolean

And I have another thread that reads the same variable and does some logic operation (without edit its values) with that and send local broadcast message with the result of this operation.

Are there concurrency problem and I have to use : synchronized method and atomic variable or it doesn't matter ?

I reflect on this problem, because there isn't atomic variable for float primitive , and because I'm scared to block Ui thread with the wrong code..

EDIT: **Other question**

> Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most
>   primitive variables (all types except long and double).

from : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Then the int,double primitive type are atomic right ? The problem is on long and double.

For example :

```
class test
{

    int c=0;
    long p=0;

    new Thread1( new Runnable(){

     public void run(){
       a=a+c;
       p=p+c;
     }
    }
    ).start();

   new Thread2( new Runnable(){

     public void run(){
       c=function();
       p=functionx();
     }
    }
    ).start();

    ....
}
```

I have to use volatile int for the visibility problems between thread or it doensn't matter ? and for the long variable should I use the atomicLong because the operation on the long primitive aren't atomic ?

p.s : I don't really understand the variable visibility problem between threads

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at another answer I gave on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397445/atomicboolean-set-flag-once-neccesary-might-a-static-boolean-be-ok/28398083#28398083) What you probably need is to make the variable volatile. UI thread, not UI thread, a thread is a thread. The importance of modifying a variable on the UI thread is so that variable will be displayed. What you are doing is sending that modified value somewhere else.

From what I understand of your question: just make the variable volatile and you should be fine.

Comment: first and foremost thanks to the answer :) I have seen other answer here on stackoverflow and I have searched guide and documentation on volatile variable, but I haven't still read .. 
If I edit a variable and in the meanwhile other thread reads the same variable, what problem can it be ? Crash beacause the variable is in inconsistent status or the only problem is that the second thread reads an old variable's status ?

Now I'm going to read you answer in other post :D

Comment: Hi ! 
I have read your answer in the other question. I have a question : why the volatile variable works well only when there are one thread that edits the volatile variable and others thread that read the same volatile variable ?

Comment: volatile does not protect a variable, it only makes the machine invalidate the caches and go to main memory (the short version.) for more detail see Cache coherence http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence

Comment: Ok. Last question :
Are primitive type (int, boolean) atomic or not ? :D

Comment: int is atomic in that a read/store will fully complete as opposed to a long which might tear if multiple threads try to read/store concurrently -- depending on the operating system, 32/64 bit etc. My last look at boolean is that it is an int underneath.

Comment: thanks for the help :)
Thus in my case where I have one thread that updates the variables int,long and boolean and different thread that reads this value, Can I use volatile for the int and boolean variable (to resolve visibility problem) and for the long variable maybe is suggest to use atomiclong ?  
P.s : I don't really understand the visibility problem between threads.

Comment: volatile for int/boolean and atomic for others seems good to me. Very few people understand threads/memory issues anyway which is why there are so many articles on the subject. Too make it easier to understand there is the happens-before scenario. A write to a volatile variable happens before a read of that variable. I don't think most people understand that either.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)
One more thing : I don't understand the problem if more of one thread write on the same volatile variable. If it is an atomic variable there isn't problem or I'm wronging ?

Comment: int x = 0; Thread-a x=1, Thread-b x=2. What is the value of x at any given time? That's why they call it a race.